# Finding the Probability Distribution (word problem)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

The number of customers $Z$ that arrive at the bank on a certain day is distributed as a Poisson random variable, with (mean) parameter $\lambda>0$. Each customer, independently of the others, either goes to the teller with probability $p$, or to the ATM, with probability $1-p$ (with $0<p<1$). Let $X$ be the number of customers that are going to the teller, and $Y$ the number of customers going to the ATM.

I need help finding the probability distribution of $X$ and the probability distribution of $Y$.

All I need is the general procedure and don't need it solved out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the general procedure

let $k \in \mathbb{N}$, by the law of total probability , we have 
$$P(X=k)=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}{P(X=k|Z=l)P(Z=l)}$$

We must have $l\geq k$, the number of clients going to the teller cannot be higher than the number of clients , therefore 
$$P(X=k)=\sum_{l=k}^{\infty}{P(X=k|Z=l)P(Z=l)}$$

Moreover, we have $$P(X=k|Z=l)=\binom{l}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{l-k}$$, we want k clients out of l  to go to the teller

and
$$P(Z=l)=\frac{\lambda^le^{-\lambda}}{l!}$$

The case for Y is identical .

Answer (score 1):

By definition of being a Poison distribution, customers are arriving at the bank independently of the time of arrival of any other customer, at a constant average rate of $\lambda$.

Of these, any customer will go to the teller with an independent probability of $p$, or to the ATM with an independent probability of $(1-p)$.   ( Which destination any customer chooses is independent of what any other customer chooses. )

So customers are going to the teller independently at constant average rate of $p\lambda$.

They are also going to the ATM independently at constant average rate of $(1-p)\lambda$.

What distributions do you anticipate the counts of *these* arrivals will have?